# How can i get url parameter in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes

This is my url -> `http://localhost:82/?search=asd`

How do I catch 'asd' in route?

I try this -> `Route::get('/?search={SearchValue}', 'TryController@search');`

But it didn't work. 
It won't even get into the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to adjust the routes. But include $request in your controller method. Then use your request object to access it.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function search(Request $request) {
    // to access the query parameters
    $search = $request->query->get('search');

    // similar but different syntax
   $search = $request->query('search');

    // generic method that checks all input including query
    $search = $request->input('search');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just only need something like this:

```
Route::get('/search', 'TryController@search')->name('try.search');
```

Once you have the route correctly set you can call:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
   $request->get('search')
```

to get the url parameter you passed into the request.